# Android compose ModalBottomSheetLayout causes enormous recomposition counts

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, compose-recomposition

I'm working with compose now for several weeks and some things are still quite challenging or weird I think.

My newest feature requires a `BottomSheet`, a `ModalBottomSheet` to be precise.

When inspecting via the Layout Inspector it shows me, that the ModalBottomSheet `sheetcontent`, that is a `surface`, produces enormous recomposition counts. (I'm talking about hundres per second):

[image: Layout Inspector recomposition counts of ModalBottomSheet Surface]

I even tried emptying the whole `ModalBottomSheet` so it's only an empty shell like this:

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    confirmStateChange = { it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded },
    skipHalfExpanded = true,
)

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = sheetState,
    sheetShape = CustomTheme.shapes.bottomSheetRadius,
    sheetContent = {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 10.sdp)) { 

        }
    }
) {

}
```

Someone experienced the same? I can not find anyone complaining about this.. But this can not be okay I think.

Comment: Show the entire @Composable function as its this function that's getting recomposed.

Comment: How do you trigger recomposition? This code alone should not trigger recomposition

Answer (score 1):

The recomposition count comes from the animation of modal bottom sheet. You can see these exact recomposition count in any animation api.

It is not really a problem unless you put the entire UI component in **sheetContent** directly. You have to create a separate composable with only [stable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability) parameters to avoid any kind of real problem. Hope this helps.